# Proper secret key management

Tags: authentication, hmac

Right now, I'm thinking that for all incoming requests, my server will check the token of the request against the token constructed from my app's global secret key for authenticity. The only way for anyone to hack is by gaining control of my server. then again, if anyone managed to gain control of your server, you're toast, it's all over, no measure can be taken to stop the attacker. is there any flaw in this argument?

Comment: Can you provide more details on your plan?

Comment: Will the app's global secret key be stored in some version control tool (git/svn/...) if yes, an attacker could try to target those services  too.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are some means by which you could make an attack more difficult or limit the impact of a breach here.

One is using per-user secrets and storing them separately.  The server would only see them in memory and some form of server sharding by user could be used to limit the number of per-user secrets exposed to a single compromised server.

Another is using a separate KMS system that generates or validates tokens.  That system would have to be hardened as well, but an attacker would then have to breach multiple layers of your system to steal the secrets.  In some KMS systems the keys are stored in the TPM so even a soft compromise of the KMS wouldn't leak the keys.  They'd have to steal the hardware itself so offline attacks of your tokens are effectively designed out.

Bear in mind that the token system may not be the weakest link here.  It's good in isolation to harden it, but to have effective overall security you need to make defense choices based on a threat model of the system this component is deployed into.